# BroadcastReceiver срабатывает неправильно

Tags: android, java

Доброго времени суток всем!
В моей программе метод `onReceive` в приемнике `StartServiceReceiver`, срабатывает по запуску программы(или по повороту экрана), в интенте приходит "android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE", как такое может быть?

```
public class KsivaFTPApacheActivity extends Activity {
Context context = null;
BroadcastReceiver StartService;
BroadcastReceiver GetStatus;
private final IntentFilter StartServiceFilter = new IntentFilter();
private final IntentFilter GetStatusFilter = new IntentFilter();
public static final String CUSTOM_INTENT = "com.imholynx.KsivaFTPApache.intent.start";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    StartServiceFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
    StartServiceFilter.addAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
    StartService = new StartServiceReceiver();  
    GetStatusFilter.addAction("AppService");
    GetStatus = new GetStatusReceiver();

    this.registerReceiver(StartService, StartServiceFilter);   
    this.registerReceiver(GetStatus, GetStatusFilter);
}
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();   
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
 }

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.unregisterReceiver(StartService);
    this.unregisterReceiver(GetStatus);
    stopService(new Intent(this, KsivaFTPApacheService.class));     
}
public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("State", intent.getAction());
        Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        {

            NetworkInfo ni = null;
            ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (ni != null)
                if (ni.isConnected()) {
                    Intent inten;
                    Log.i("INFO", ((Integer) Files.size()).toString());
                    if (!Files.isEmpty())
                        for (int i = 0; i < Files.size(); i++) {
                            if (Files.elementAt(i).Status == false) {
                                Log.i("INFO","send "+ Files.elementAt(i).FileName);
                                inten = new Intent(context,KsivaFTPApacheService.class);
                                Log.i("INFO", ((Integer) Files.size()).toString());
                                Log.i("INFO2", ((Integer) i).toString());
                                inten.putExtra("FileName",Files.elementAt(i).FileName);
                                inten.putExtra("Action",Files.elementAt(i).Action);
                                inten.putExtra("ID", i);
                                context.startService(inten);
                            }
                        }
                }
        }

    }

}

public class GetStatusReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("AppService")) {
            Log.i("AppService", ((Integer) intent.getIntExtra("Data", 1)).toString());
            Files.elementAt(intent.getIntExtra("Data", 1)).Status = true;
        }
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вернуться к вопросу, который я задавал год назад и на который не смог найти решения.

---

В ОС Android существует такой вид Интентов как **Sticky Intents**(липкие). Основное отличие их от обычных Интентов в том, что обычные приходят в момент посылания, а липкие можно получить в любое время при регистрации приёмника.

В моем случае, при регистрации приемника в него сразу приходил липкий Интент, который хранил последнее изменение, которое произошло с WiFi. Именно приход этого Интента я и не мог объяснить.

Узнать является ли данный Интент липким можно в **onReceive()** приёмника с помощью метода **isInitialStickyBroadcast()**:

```
public class StartServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       if(!isInitialStickyBroadcast()){
          // Реагируем только на не липкие Интенты
       }
    }
}
```

Надеюсь, что кому-нибудь поможет мой ответ. Ну а я получил удовольствие от того, что нашел решение.

Answer (score 4):

А чего же вы еще хотите? У вас же фильтр бродкаста настроен на изменение статуса wi-fi подключения `WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` - естественно интент такой и будет приходить в ресивере бродкаста.

P.S. Обратите внимание на нарушения в своем коде [Java naming convention](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). В частности, переменная `StartServiceFilter`, должна именоваться `startServiceFilter` - мелочь вроде, но глаза режет конкретно.

Comment: Так я и жду, что он придёт при изменении статуса wifi. А он приходит ещё и при запуске программы и при повороте экрана...

Comment: Так и не понял тогда вопроса - можно подробнее пояснить чего вы хотите?

Comment: Попробую по порядку.
В данной программе
Я запускаю программу и сразу приходит android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
Переворачиваю телефон и опять приходит android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE
При этом статус wifi в телефоне не меняется

Comment: ну как бы вы добавили StartServiceFilter.addAction(CUSTOM_INTENT);
Так что ничего удивительного

Answer (score 1):

чтобы при повороте экрана не срабатывал onReceive(), добавь в манифест в активити следующее:

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

a если версия Android выше чем 3, то надо добавить еще **screenSize**

эта строка говорит о том, что ты сам будешь обрабатывать изменение ориентации устройства (на самом деле не будешь ;) )

Comment: Спасибо огромное, немного поздно, но зато теперь буду знать.